# Hibernate, use the entity already persisted in DB to link with owning side instead of creating a new one if the owned entity is same

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to the hibernate, I have a spring boot project using hibernate and spring data jpa.

I have a entity TestCase which have one InputJSON, different TestCase can have same InputJSON.
Below is the snippet

**TestCase.java**

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", initialValue = 1, 
sequenceName = "test_case_id_sequence ", allocationSize = 50)
private long testCaseId;

private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "input_JSON_ID")
private InputJSON inputJSON;
...
```

**InputJSON.java**

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", allocationSize = 50, 
sequenceName ="input_JSON_ID_Sequence",initialValue = 1)
private long inputJSONId;

private String json;
private String header;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "inputJSON")
private List<TestCase> testCase;
```

I override equals() and hashcode() in both the entities.
When i persist as below it works fine and hibernates link my testcase with same inputJson.

```java
InputJSON json1=new InputJSON();
json1.setHeader("header");
json1.setJson("json");

TestCase tc1=new TestCase();
tc1.setName("test1");
tc1.setInputJSON(json1);

TestCase tc2=new TestCase();
tc2.setName("test2");
tc2.setInputJSON(json1);

repository.save(tc1);
repository.save(tc2);
```

but when I persist like this, hibernate is creating two rows for InputJSON.

```java
InputJSON json1=new InputJSON();
json1.setHeader("header");
json1.setJson("json");

InputJSON json2=new InputJSON();
json2.setHeader("header");
json2.setJson("json");

TestCase tc1=new TestCase();
tc1.setName("test1");
tc1.setInputJSON(json1);

TestCase tc2=new TestCase();
tc2.setName("test2");
tc2.setInputJSON(json2);

repository.save(tc1);
repository.save(tc2);
```

**UPDATE:**

i am receiving testcase and input json information in a DTO, the problem is i am receiving different DTOs for different Testcases and i have to create sensible models out of them.So to know that two jsons are equal i have to programmatic ally compare them before persisting in DB which i want to avoid(if it can be avoided) and let hibernate handle them.

InputDTO.java

```java
private String testCaseDescription;
private boolean skipTest;
private String params;
private String headerJson;
private String inputJson;
```

where repository is the auto wired instance of my JPARepository.

Is there a way or workaround in hibernate to create only one row if the JSONS are same, i have tried some thing and i know i can fetch the JSONS form DB and compare them with my new json and if they are same used the already persisted one instead of creating a new one, i have also do some digging on use of equals and hashcode by hibernate and I found hibernates only uses them in Set.

Comment: have you tried to persist the `json1` object before you set it in the `tc` object ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse things.

You need to set `testCase` list and then save the `json1` object

Comment: I have updated the question, i have no way to know if testcase1 and testcase2 using the same json or not.